# GCP Cloud Storage(GCS) new object / changes notifications to email / text ,message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, google-cloud-pubsub

We are storing some of our SQL dumps from AWS RDS to GCP cloud storage as a long term secondary backup .For the past four days the data were not transferred to GCP, on analysis we found out that was because of daylight saving changes and fixed the issue.

Now in the future we would like to get some notification from GCP to email / text message - positive scenario /pager duty - negative scenario (Email alone at this time). Postive scenario for emailing is successful upload of a new file to GCS bucket. But as google does not have any native support for emailing or text, Please suggest us a solution. I have configured the the following

1. Configured bucket to notify changes to pub sub https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes
2. Configured the pub /sub notification as a pull delivery type
   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications

But now how do I send email / text out of GCP. We are Major AWS shop. Can we use SES or SNS or any other type of notification to get the data out of PUB/SUB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use SES or SNS or any other type of notification to get the
>   data out of PUB/SUB?

Yes. I have done this (SES) using Google Cloud Functions with a Pub/Sub trigger. I am assuming SNS would be just as easy.

However, I find it much easier to setup Google Cloud Functions to use an SMTP client to fire off an email. I have also used Twilio to fire off SMS text messages.

To use AWS SNS or SES, you will need to package the boto3 libraries with your deployment and your AWS credentials. You can also use the AWS REST interface so that no external libraries are required.

For an email SMTP client, Google Cloud Functions has `smtplib` included, so this is a very easy path. You just need an email username and password to SMTP. For this I use Gmail or Office 365 credentials. 20 lines of python code and you are done.

[EDIT]

When using Google Cloud Functions to send email, use SSL for the transport. For Office 365 and Gmail this port 587. Do not attempt to use port 25, which does not use SSL, as almost everyone blocks port 25.

Comment: I have used google cloud function to send email via smtp but the cloud function seem to be blocking the SMTP ports. [https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips] . Can you tell me how did you get over restriction.

Comment: I don't have any problems, nor did I have to make any changes. However, I only use SMTP SSL. For Gmail and Office 365 this is port 587. Don't try to use port 25 which is blocked by almost everyone. The link that you provided is broken (404 error).

Comment: Thank you. Actual Link : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips  I am able to use the port 587 and the email functionality is working fine with Amazon SES. Only port 25 is blocked. I have given my code below in the Answer. Also I am not sure if its a new functionality, Cloud function can directly take the trigger from GCS without a pub/sub in middle and we can configure it for different function such as create, delete etc. So whenever there is a new file creation it directly calls the cloud function.

Answer (score 0):

1. We can configure GCS bucket to trigger the cloud functions directly for the below changes to the GCS bucket.

   1. Finalize - Create
   2. Delete
   3. Archive
   4. Metadata update

Tutorial : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage

2. Cloud function with python 3.7 to trigger the email using Amazon SES SMTP Interface.

   ```
   import smtplib
   import email.utils
   from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
   from email.mime.text import MIMEText

   def email_notify(event, context):
       """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
       Args:
       event (dict): Event payload.
       context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
       """
       file = event
       print(f"Processing file: {file['name']}.")
       BUCKET = file['bucket']
       FILE = file['name']
       CREATED = file['timeCreated']
       UPDATED = file['updated']
       # Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
       # This address must be verified.
       SENDER = 'sender-email-address'  
       SENDERNAME = 'no-reply'

       # Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
       # is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
       RECIPIENT  = 'recepient-email-address'

       # Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
       USERNAME_SMTP = "SMTP-USERNAME"

       # Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
       PASSWORD_SMTP = "SMTP-PASSWORD"

       # (Optional) the name of a configuration set to use for this message.
       # If you comment out this line, you also need to remove or comment out
       # the "X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET:" header below.
       # CONFIGURATION_SET = "ConfigSet"

       # If you're using Amazon SES in an AWS Region other than US West (Oregon),
       # replace email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com with the Amazon SES SMTP
       # endpoint in the appropriate region.
       HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
       PORT = 587

       # The subject line of the email.
       SUBJECT = 'Successfull upload of file {} to GCS bucket {}'.format(FILE,BUCKET)

       # The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
       BODY_TEXT = ("File upload to GCS bucket\r\n"
                    "Bucket-Name: {}\r\n"
                    "File-Name: {}\r\n"
                    "File-Create-Date: {}\r\n"
                    "File-Update-Date: {}\r\n"
                   ).format(BUCKET,FILE,CREATED,UPDATED)

       # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
       msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
       msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
       msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr((SENDERNAME, SENDER))
       msg['To'] = RECIPIENT
       # Comment or delete the next line if you are not using a configuration set
       # msg.add_header('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET',CONFIGURATION_SET)

       # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
       part1 = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT, 'plain')
       # part2 = MIMEText(BODY_HTML, 'html')

       # Attach parts into message container.
       # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
       # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
       msg.attach(part1)
       # msg.attach(part2)

       # Try to send the message.
       try:
           server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST, PORT)
           server.ehlo()
           server.starttls()
           #stmplib docs recommend calling ehlo() before & after starttls()
           server.ehlo()
           server.login(USERNAME_SMTP, PASSWORD_SMTP)
           server.sendmail(SENDER, RECIPIENT, msg.as_string())
           server.close()
       # Display an error message if something goes wrong.
       except Exception as e:
           print ("Error: ", e)
       else:
           print ("Email sent!")
   ```